# groupby multiple value columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I need to do a fuzzy `groupby` where a single record can be in one or more groups.

I have a `DataFrame` like this:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'score1' : pandas.Series(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']), 'score2' : pd.Series(['b', 'a', 'k', 'n', 'c'])})
```

Output:

```
  score1  score2
0   a       b
1   b       a
2   c       k
3   d       n
4   e       c
```

I wish to have groups like this:
[image]

The group keys should be the union of the unique values between `score1` and `score2`. Record `0` should be in groups `a` and `b` because it contains both score values. Similarly record `1` should be in groups `b` and `a`; record `2` should be in groups `c` and `k` and so on.

I've tried doing a groupby on two columns like this:

```
In [192]: score_groups = pd.groupby(['score1', 'score2'])
```

However I get the group keys as tuples - (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 8), etc, instead of unique group keys where records can be in multiple groups. The output is shown below:

```
In [192]: score_groups.groups

Out[192]: {('a', 'b'): [0],
           ('b', 'a'): [1],
           ('c', 'k'): [2],
           ('d', 'n'): [3],
           ('e', 'c'): [4]}
```

Also, **I need the indexes preserved** because I'm using them for another operation later. 
Please help!

Comment: I think your data-frame probably needs to be transposed.  If your columns were: 'index,score_name,score' this would be trivial.  Look at pandas.melt to transform your dataframe.

Comment: So.... you just need to persevere the original index?

Comment: Yes, and I also need access to the actual groups in the GroupBy object so that I can perform some operations on the contents of the groups. I've posted my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine the two `columns` in a single `column` using e.g. `pd.concat()`:

```
s = pd.concat([test['score1'], test['score2'].rename(columns={'score2': 'score1'})]).reset_index()
s.columns = ['val', 'grp']

   val grp
0    0   a
1    1   b
2    2   c
3    3   d
4    4   e
5    0   b
6    1   a
7    2   k
8    3   n
9    4   c
```

And then `.groupby()` on `'grp'` and collect `'val'` in a `list`:

```
s = s.groupby('grp').apply(lambda x: x.val.tolist())

a    [0, 1]
b    [1, 0]
c    [2, 4]
d       [3]
e       [4]
k       [2]
n       [3]
```

or, if you prefer `dict`:

```
s.to_dict()

{'e': [4], 'd': [3], 'n': [3], 'k': [2], 'a': [0, 1], 'c': [2, 4], 'b': [1, 0]}
```

Or, to the same effect in a single step, skipping renaming the columns:

```
test.unstack().reset_index(-1).groupby(0).apply(lambda x: x.level_1.tolist())

a    [0, 1]
b    [1, 0]
c    [2, 4]
d       [3]
e       [4]
k       [2]
n       [3]
```

Comment: The concatenation operation adds new index values. I need the indexes preserved because I'm using them for something else.
I've actually created a separate column that replicates the original index. Is it possible to do a `groupby()` that stores this column 's values instead of the actual index?

Comment: I just updated my answer, looks like the original data changed or I copied it wrong before? I think the `index` values are captured properly?

Comment: You're right. I changed the question to more closely represent my data. 
Your answer does give me the correct indices now, however because of the `apply()` function, access to the original `GroupBy` object and its contents is lost. I can always use the dictionary values to get the rows from the original dataFrame, but it would be nice to have the `GroupBy` object itself.

Comment: You can access the groupby object before using apply; the original index is preserved in the val column.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1494637/stefan)'s help, I solved it like this.

```
In (283): frame1 = test[['score1']]
          frame2 = test[['score2']]
          frame2.rename(columns={'score2': 'score1'}, inplace=True)

          test = pandas.concat([frame1, frame2])

          test

Out[283]:   
   score1
0   a
1   b
2   c
3   d
4   e
0   b
1   a
2   k
3   n
4   c
```

Notice the duplicate indices. The indexes have been preserved, which is what I wanted. Now, lets get to business - the group by operation.

```
In (283): groups = test.groupby('score1')

          groups.get_group('a') # Get group with key a

Out[283]: 
    score1
0   a
1   a

In (283): groups.get_group('b') # Get group with key b

Out[283]: 
    score1
1   b
0   b

In (283): groups.get_group('c') # Get group with key c

Out[283]: 
    score1
2   c
4   c

In (283): groups.get_group('k') # Get group with key k

Out[283]: 
    score1
2   k
```

I'm baffled by how pandas retrieves rows with the correct index even though they are duplicated. As I understand, the group by operation uses an inverted index data structure to store the references (indexes) to rows. Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Anyone who answers this will have their answer accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

Reorganizing your data for ease of manipulation (having multiple value columns for the same data will always cause you headaches).

```
import pandas as pd

test = pd.DataFrame({'score1' : pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']), 'score2' : pd.Series([2, 1, 8, 9, 3], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])})

test['name'] = test.index
result = pd.melt(test, id_vars=['name'], value_vars=['score1', 'score2'])

  name variable  value
0    a   score1      1
1    b   score1      2
2    c   score1      3
3    d   score1      4
4    e   score1      5
5    a   score2      2
6    b   score2      1
7    c   score2      8
8    d   score2      9
9    e   score2      3
```

Now you have only one column for your value and it's easy to groupby score or select by your name column:

```
   hey = result.groupby('value')
   hey.groups
   #below are the indices that you care about
   {1: [0, 6], 2: [1, 5], 3: [2, 9], 4: [3], 5: [4], 8: [7], 9: [8]}
```

Comment: This could work nicely, but it doesn't preserve the indexes. When I do a groupby on `result`, the indexes in the groups are now of result, not of the original dataframe. Also, `result.groupby('value')` contains groups of `result`'s rows, not the original dataset's rows.
I've updated my question.

Comment: @lostsoul29 - yes, they're indices on the new dataframe, you just have to use them to index in to that result and it will give you what you want.  If you have to preserve the original index you should save it as a column not an index.